# Не работают функции

Tags: python, функции, pygame

Пытаюсь написать игру на библиотеке пайгейм, написал несколько функций, но ни одна из них не работает, несколько раз перепроверял их написание ошибок не нашёл.
Функции абсолютно такие же,
как у других def name_():
...
При выполнении кода ни какой ошибки не возникает, но код который находится в функции не выполняется.
Функцию вызываю так:
...
name_()
Весь код и функции пишу в одном файле, так как при написании функции в другом файле, она всё равно не будет работать в основном коде.

```py
    import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

sc_value = (500, 500)
sc = pygame.display.set_mode(sc_value)
x = 200
y = 400
speed = 10

bg = pygame.image.load("images/Ktulhu_calling_me.png")

character_image = "images\character.png"
ground = pygame.image.load("images/pixil-frame-0 (2).png")
character = pygame.image.load(character_image)

ground_rectt = ground.get_rect()
character_rect = character.get_rect()
ground_rectt.top = character_rect.bottom


def k_down(n):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            n += speed
            character_image = "images\character_right.png"
            if n >= 500:
                n -= 20
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            n -= speed
            character_image = "images\character.png"
            if n < 0:
                n += 20


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        k_down(x)

    character = pygame.image.load(character_image)
    sc.blit(bg, (-320, 0))
    sc.blit(ground, (0, 450))
    sc.blit(character, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: А как мы должны понять что не так, не видя код, откуда эти функции вызываются? А может они вызываются, но вы этого не замечаете. Остается только гадать

Comment: Хорошо. Что такое `x` в вызове `k_down(x)`? И почему вы думаете, что функция не выполняется, по каким признакам? В приведённом коде вы меняете внутренние переменные функции и больше ничего не делаете. Внешне это никак не проявляется.

Comment: Я лично не буду голосовать за переоткрытие вопроса, пока вы не ответите на уточняющие вопросы.

Comment: CrazyElf
Если код будет находится в функции, которую я потом вызову, этот код не выполнится, но если этот же код будет в основном цикле игры, он будет выполнятся, поэтому я и подумал, что проблема в них, или я что то не так делаю. Если это так, пожалуйста объясните мне мою ошибку.

Comment: Если это полный текст функции `k_down`, то всё, что она делает - это меняет свои локальные переменные. Эффекта от вызова этой функции вы не заметите. Вам нужно разобраться чем отличаются глобальные и локальные переменные. Переменную, переданную в функцию как параметр, тоже без толку менять, если вы её не возвращаете и не запоминаете при вызове функции. Лучше всего передавать все параметры в функцию в явном виде и получать из функции обратно тоже, вернув изменённые значения через `return`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def k_down(n):
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            n += speed
            character_image = "images\character_right.png"
            if n >= 500:
                n -= 20
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            n -= speed
            character_image = "images\character.png"
            if n < 0:
                n += 20
```

Эта функция меняет только свои **локальные** переменные - параметр функции `n` и переменную `character_image`. Они не имеют никакого отношения к внешним для функции переменным.

В качестве решения обычно начинающие объявляют все подряд переменные глобальными, но так лучше не делать (долго объяснять почему). Лучше всего передавать и возвращать все переменные в функцию в явном виде:

```py
def k_down(n, character_image):
    # здесь мы работаем с этими переменными, как-то их меняем (или не меняем)
    ...
    # и потом обязательно возвращаем из функции их текущие значения
    return n, character_image

# полученные из функции значения нужно сохранить в переменные основного кода
n, character_image = k_down(x, character_image)
```